# SVG file is redownloaded a lot

Tags: html, svg

Im using `object` and `use` in order to have a single file for all my svg icons. But what Im seeing is that `icons.svg` file gets redownloaded every time a new icon is used in application. It's not strictly for *every* icon but it seems to happen very often. I couldn't diagnose it in my searches.

Is this normal behavior? Should it keep downloading the file? Am I just supposed to cache it?

---

How I include svg file to `index.html`:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/static/icons.svg" style="display: none;"></object>
```

How I use icons in various places:

```
<use href="/static/icons.svg#foo"></use>
<use href="/static/icons.svg#bar"></use>
```

Example `icons.svg`:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="foo" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="69.37" cy="37.27" r="16.97"/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="bar" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="69.37" cy="37.27" r="16.97"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the HTTP headers? Maybe your server adds a `cache-control` or `expires` header that prevents caching in the browser? In addition, I can see no need for your `<object>` tag. The `href` should be enough to point your browser to the right asset.

Comment: @ccprog I haven't set any caching headers because it's still in development. What Im interested in knowing is that if this is a normal behavior? Why it redownloads (even if response has 304 header) when file is already downloaded?

Comment: No, it is not. That is why I asked for headers. I can't see such a behavior for example on my own website (Apache <-> Firefox) that uses the same pattern (as I said, without that `<object>` tag.)

Comment: @ccprog Very annoying indeed. I removed `object` and everything works like before but it still requests the file again and again. It's SPA but I don't see how that would change anything.